# Storing the result of wc in a variable

Tags: shell, terminal

I am trying:

```
y=$(wc -l email.txt)
```

It's giving the count of lines and also the filename `email.txt`. I don't understand why.

I'm using ubuntu 13.04

Comment: The result of WC can point to a const=null after you flush it.

Comment: Your recent edit "fixed" the code (by using `wc -l < email.txt` rather than `wc -l email.txt`). Please don't do that; it means the question no longer makes any sense. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @MennoGouw: I don't understand what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: @KeithThompson Bad joke about a Water Closet i guess.

Comment: @MennoGouw: Ah. That term isn't used much on this side of the Atlantic. Carry on.

Comment: Figured that already, i'm from Holland and it is a regular term here. I guess just high class British use it in there vocabulary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
y=$(wc -l < email.txt) | tr -d ' ')
```

Comment: working as i needed , but I want to know that if we even delete ' ' through tr -d , then the actual value in y will b the number of lines in .txt file ??

Comment: `tr -d ' '` has been used to strip spaced before number generated by `wc` command.

Comment: Alternatively, using an arithmetic context: `((y=$(wc -l < email.txt) ))`. That will automatically ignore spaces...

Comment: this is working, I am having a trouble other than this, I want to access this text file(email.txt) from outside the script into the script, means somehow I get access to this file , then I get able to do calculation with it. How can I access this file into script

Comment: May be you should post your script in question to that I can understand better and suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke `wc` with a file name as an argument, it prints that file name along with the number of lines, words, and characters in the file (or just the number of lines if you use `wc -l`).

If you run `wc -l` with its input *redirected* from a file, the `wc` command doesn't have access to the file name, so it doesn't print it.

And in particular, if you use `wc -l` it prints *just* the number of lines (followed by a newline); there are no extra blanks, at least with the version of `wc` I use.

(This is slightly unfortunate; many Unix text-processing tools behave the same way with `command file.txt` and `command < file.txt`, but `wc` doesn't.)

So all you need is:

```
y=$(wc -l < email.txt)
```

If for some reason you still wanted to pass `email.txt` as a command line argument, you could use `sed` to select just the number of lines:

```
y=$(wc email.txt | sed 's/ .*//')
```

The `sed` command changes the output

```
1234 email.txt
```

to just

```
1234
```

and might be useful for tools other than `wc` that print extra information regardless of how they're invoked (see `sha1sum`, for example).

Comment: this is working, I am having a trouble other than this, I want to access this text file(email.txt) from outside the script into the script, means somehow I get access to this file , then I get able to do calculation with it. How can I access this file into script

Comment: @user2831683: Post a new question.